# How to modify hidden autogenerated checkbox of `CheckBoxFor` in MVC4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox, html-helper

As many have stated the following `Html` helper of the `MVC` generates a hidden checkbox, but i cannot find nowhere how to modify the class of the autogenerated checkbox input. The problem is that somehow the hidden checkbox interferes with the normal one and destroys the appearance of the `css`. For that reason i need to update the hidden checkbox to include the same css class as the normal checkbox. Is it possible to do that preferably with the MVC?

Server `Html` helper:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive, new { @class="px"})
<span class="lbl">Active user</span>
```

Generated html:

```
<input class="px" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
<span class="lbl">Active user</span>
```

**Edit**

After request i'm posting what i found from the css because comes from an external library called pixel-admin and as i can see is optimized for ie8.

```
.gt-ie8 input.px {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: -1000000px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl:before {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl:after {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px:checked + .lbl:after {
  display: block;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl:before,
.gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl:after {
  margin: 2px 3px -3px -20px !important;
}
.gt-ie8 input[type="checkbox"].px + .lbl:before {
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.gt-ie8 input[type="checkbox"].px + .lbl:after {
  content: "\f00c";
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  text-align: center;
}
.gt-ie8 input[type="radio"].px + .lbl:before {
  border-radius: 999999px;
}
.gt-ie8 input[type="radio"].px + .lbl:after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled,
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled + .lbl,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled + .lbl,
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled + .lbl:before,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled + .lbl:before,
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled + .lbl:after,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled + .lbl:after {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled + .lbl:before,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled + .lbl:before {
  background: #eee !important;
  border-color: #d6d6d6 !important;
}
.gt-ie8 input.px:disabled + .lbl:after,
.gt-ie8 input.px.disabled + .lbl:after {
  opacity: .5 !important;
}
```

Comment: You could always use jquery to add a class name, but how is the hidden input interfering?

Comment: The `class="px"` applies a style to the checkbox and if you notice both checkboxes have the same name. I believe this "duplicity" causes problems to the css so the checkbox is not visible. When i remove the class or the hidden checkbox using chrome dev tools it's shows up.

Comment: Yes I know both checkboxes have the same name (that's what its supposed to be). What is the definition for the `px` style?

Comment: @JorgeCode this "duplicity" can not affect css in any way. Please post your css

Comment: @malik i posted the css. I really don't know but the thing is when i remove the class or the hidden checkbox the other one pops up.

Comment: You have a number of selectors that use `gt-ie8 input.px + .lbl` or similar which is selecting the `.lbl` span which immediately after the `.px` checkbox, but there is no `.lbl` element immediately after the `.px` input (the element immediately after the `.px` input is the hidden input). You need to change your selectors (could be just `gt-ie8.lbl`)